# Задача на функции и методы. Java

Tags: java, массивы, функции, методы

Определить, является ли массив отсортированным по возрастанию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они напоминают ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем варианте метода создается копия входного массива, а после копия сортируется и сравнивается с оригиналом. Метод:

```
 static boolean isSorted(int [] array){
    int [] arr= Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    if(Arrays.equals(arr, array)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Можно сделать версию с Stream API:

```
static boolean isSorted(int [] array){
    int [] val= IntStream.of(array).
            sorted().
            toArray();

    if(Arrays.equals(val, array)) return true;

    return false;
}
```